# Magento: How to search programmatically in customer collection

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I'm trying to build a search script to retrieve entries from customer collection. The trick is that the normal "OR" condition works only for the first entry.

This is the code I have so far:

```
$customers = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    if($_searchTerm = $this->getRequest()->getParam('q')){
        $customers->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
                array('attribute' => 'firstname', 'like' => $_searchTerm),
                array('attribute' => 'lastname', 'like' => $_searchTerm),
                array('attribute' => 'email', 'like' => '%' . $_searchTerm . '%'),
                array('attribute' => 'phone', 'like' => '%' . $_searchTerm . '%'), /* valid field in my collection*/
            )
        );
    }
```

I've tried with wildcard "%" also but still no proper result.
Most likely i'm missing something here.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks OK to me.  When I test the above the resulting query ends with `WHERE ... ((at_firstname.value LIKE 'TEST') OR (at_lastname.value LIKE 'TEST') OR (e.email LIKE '%TEST%') OR (at_phone.value LIKE '%TEST%'))` which is expected.  What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: @clockworkgeek I've used the ->getSelect() method to show the "Select" sql query and everything looks normal. I have 2 customers: Ion and Daniel. When i use the script it behaves like he's only searching within "Ion" customer and not "Daniel". All the results are shown for "Ion" customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Its 100% working for me

```
public function customerSearch($data) {
        $customerFactory = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');
        $collection = $customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                ->addAttributeToFilter('sponsor_id', array('eq' => $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId()))
                ->addAttributeToFilter(
                        array(
                            array('attribute' => 'firstname', 'like' => '%' . $data . '%'),
                            array('attribute' => 'lastname', 'like' => '%' . $data . '%')
                        ))->load();
        $customer = $collection->getData();
        echo json_encode($customer);
        exit;
    }
```

Where sponsor_id is my custom attribute for customer and $data is simple string to find customer by firstname or lastname. I hope this will resolve your issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My stupidity exceeds me this time. I've used another attribute in my query that Magento had some issues when filtering it, a custom attribute created with a module. Thanks @clockworkgeek for supporting me.